# How to use moment-timezone in Angular 2 class?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

I am trying to use moment-timezone in my class.
This is my typings.

```
"moment": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/moment/moment.d.ts#a1575b96ec38e916750629839d2110cb96210f89",
"moment-timezone": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/moment-timezone/moment-timezone.d.ts#f8a90040348e83926f44e690b209769c4f88b961"
```

My import:

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
import * as tz from 'moment-timezone';
```

My usage:

```
var jun = moment("2014-06-01T12:00:00Z");
jun.tz('America/Los_Angeles').format('ha z');
```

My error:

```
Property 'tz' does not exist on type 'Moment'.
```

Answer (score 13):

Use [Typescript `@types`](https://rynop.wordpress.com/2016/09/22/headache-of-managing-typescript-declaration-files-solved/) packages and import it via `import * as moment from 'moment-timezone';`  You can use all `moment` methods and member vars as `moment-timezone` exports them.

I have a complete example using SystemJS at
[How to use moment-timezone in Angular2 via SystemJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39844351/how-to-use-moment-timezone-in-angular2-via-systemjs)

Answer (score 13):

Please try this code:

```
import * as moment from 'moment-timezone';

   export class Page1 {  

     public setdate = moment(); // today date
     constructor(){
       this.setdate.tz("Asia/Singapore").format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
       console.log(this.setdate.tz("Asia/Singapore").format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue and solved it this way:

Typings (ambientDependencies):

```
"moment": "registry:dt/moment#2.8.0+20160316155526",
"moment-timezone": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/moment-timezone/moment-timezone.d.ts#f8a90040348e83926f44e690b209769c4f88b961"
```

Import:

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
import 'moment-timezone'
```

Usage:

```
moment("2014-06-01T12:00:00Z")
  .tz('America/Los_Angeles')
  .format('ha z');
```

So, basically I'm doing .tz() function on moment imported object (which in fact does not exist), but the import of moment-timezone extends it with additional functions.

I'm also using systemjs-plugin-json to properly load json object with timezone definitions inside moment-timezone library.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Doing a direct import will add ~1MB to your build size. Careful

Answer (score 8):

I will update this for 2020.

```
$ npm install moment-timezone @types/moment-timezone

import moment from 'moment-timezone';

...

// do this - outside of any class is fine    
moment.tz.add('America/Los_Angeles|PST PDT|80 70|01010101010|1Lzm0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Rd0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0 Op0 1zb0');


...

someMethod() {
    const m = moment(the_date);
    ...
    const mFormatted = m.tz('America/Los_Angeles').format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZZ');
}
```

Timezone defs can be found at https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/blob/develop/data/packed/latest.json.  I use this to define my own rather than read them all in.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful. However, I found that the index.js file in the latest moment-timezone package loads all of the latest data. So, defining your own is redundant.

Comment: Yes but then you are loading all of them unnecessarily.  Not hard to add one extra line if that is all you need.  At 10 extra lines the pre-defined solution may be better.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
import moment from 'moment-timezone';
```

This import fix a lot of strange issues on my project.

---

Why?

In `moment-timezone` package you can see

```
require("moment-timezone") === require("moment")
export = moment;
```

at the end of `moment-timezone\index.d.ts` file.