# How to use moment-timezone in Angular2 via SystemJs

Tags: javascript, angular, momentjs, systemjs

I'm using Angular2 via [angular2-seed](https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed) (which uses SystemJS) and trying to load [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/guessing-user-timezone/) and use `moment.tz.guess()` specifically.

I import via:

```
import * as moment from 'moment-timezone';
```

When I do this I get the following error in my browser:

`GET /node_modules/moment-timezone/data/packed/latest.json.js 404 (Not Found)`

anuglar2-seed uses `defaultJSExtensions` which I think is why the incorrect `.js` is being added, so I figured I could just turn this off for `moment-timezone` in `tools/config/project.config.ts` like so:

```
this.SYSTEM_BUILDER_CONFIG.packages['moment-timezone'] = {
  defaultExtension: false

//I have also tried:
      map: {
        '/node_modules/moment-timezone/data/packed/latest.json.js': '/node_modules/moment-timezone/data/packed/latest.json',
        '/node_modules/moment-timezone/data/packed/latest.json': '/node_modules/moment-timezone/data/packed/latest.json'
      }
};
```

However, this is not working.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: my environment is using webpack, but I tried `import * as mt from 'moment-timezone';` also which didn't work. I then tried `import from 'moment-timezone';` and that worked for me. I also have `moment` installed too. Hope that works for you.

Comment: @Caleb When you say `didn't work` was it adding the incorrect `.js` extension to the `.json` file?  Doing `import from 'moment-timezone';` still adds the `.js` to the end. I'm confident this is a SystemJS configuration issue

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is, unless you tell SystemJS that you want to use the `moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020.min.js` file it will by default load `moment/index.js` which does a require of the tz data.

Here are the steps to configure and use correctly:

`npm install moment moment-timezone --save` and `npm install @types/moment @types/moment-timezone --save-dev`

In my component I do `import * as moment from 'moment-timezone';`.

You [configure SystemJS](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/config-api.md#packages) like:

```
...
packages: {
      'moment-timezone': {
        main: 'builds/moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020.min.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
```

You can then use `console.log(moment.tz.guess());`

For [angular2-seed](https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed) you do this:

`project.config.ts`:

```
...
 constructor() {

    this.NPM_DEPENDENCIES = [
      ...this.NPM_DEPENDENCIES,
      {src: 'moment', inject: 'libs'},
      {src: 'moment-timezone/builds/moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020.min.js', inject: 'libs'},
    ];

...
    const mtzc = {
      main: 'builds/moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020.min.js',
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    };

    this.SYSTEM_BUILDER_CONFIG.packages['moment-timezone'] = mtzc;
    this.SYSTEM_CONFIG_DEV.packages['moment-timezone'] = mtzc;
  }
```