# How do I allow user to select timezone in Angular2 ? Is there such a country/ timezone control picker?

Tags: angular, timezone-offset

I am unable to find an angular 2 control that will allow selection of a country and timezone (such as US-Los Angeles, etc.). Please guide.
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use moment JS:
https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/

There are a lot of tutorials and questions asked and answered about this on stackoverflow, here are several examples of how to do this:

[How to Include moment-timezone in Angular 2 App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38674835/how-to-include-moment-timezone-in-angular-2-app)

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-moment

[How to use moment-timezone in Angular 2 class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37540311/how-to-use-moment-timezone-in-angular-2-class)

https://github.com/mishguruorg/angular-timezone-selector